# JSON.parse chokes on double-quote string

Tags: ruby, json

So I have a ruby object:

```
PAGE_SIZES = {
  letter_size:      { width: '51em', height: '51em' },
  half_letter_size: { width: '51em', height: '33em' },
  custom:           { width: '42em', height: '51em' }
}
```

and a getter method:

```
def page_sizes
  PAGE_SIZES.to_json
end
```

and a corresponding JS function in the page:

```
var pageSizes = JSON.parse("#{@bulletin_setting.page_sizes}");
```

but the string is sent with quotes unescaped:

```
console.log (JSON.parse("{"letter_size":{"width":"51em","height":"51em"},"half_letter_size":{"width":"51em","height":"33em"},"custom":{"width":"42em","height":"51em"}}"));
```

which gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I tried gsubing all the double quotes with single quotes:

```
console.log (JSON.parse("{'letter_size':{'width':'51em','height':'51em'},'half_letter_size':{'width':'51em','height':'33em'},'custom':{'width':'42em','height':'51em'}}"));
```

but that didn't work. I must be missing something really obvious, this should be dead simple.

mu is too short marked this as a duplicate. The problem is the same (unescaped double quotes in a JS string) but the context is different. To use the unescape_javascript method you would need to use an include in the controller, as the method is intended for views. So I felt the gsub method was a cleaner implementation. But that's just my opinion.

... and here's what worked for me:

```
  PAGE_SIZES = {
  'margin'          => { 'top' => '0.5', 'bottom' => '0.5', 'left' => '0.5', 'right' => '0.5' },
  'letter_size'      => { 'width' => '8.5', 'height' => '11' },
  'half_letter_size' => { 'width' => '5.5', 'height' => '8.5' },
  'custom'           => { 'width' => '7',   'height' => '8.5' },
}


  def page_sizes
    PAGE_SIZES
  end

var pageSizes = $.parseJSON("#{j @bulletin_setting.page_sizes.to_json}");
```

Comment: Try the answer I just updated

Comment: Hmmm... thanks, but I wouldn't call it an exact duplicate... escape_javascript is for views, it requires an include to use in a method (though it does the same thing)... I wound up using PAGE_SIZES.to_json.gsub(/\"/, "\\\"")

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` doesn't accept a key (and value) that was surrounded single quotation. You should use double quotation.

```
JSON.parse("{'letter_size':{'width':'51em', 'height': '51em'}}")
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1(…)

JSON.parse('{"letter_size":{"width":"51em", "height": "51em"}}');
// Object {letter_size: Object}
```